# Front-end: scale text as background to window size

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, frontend, scale

I have this background i created, the big "HOME". There is no background image only a p tag:
[image]

```html
<main id="app homepage">
      <p class="bg_home noselect " id="bg_home">HOME</p>
```

with this style:

```css
.bg_home {
  color: var(--main-bg-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px var(--text-stoke);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(1, 1.2);
  font-size: 42vw;
}
```

As you can see, to obtain this look I've had to scale it and I would like it to sort of keep its height to always override a bit the brown area.

I thought that i could use some javascript to scale it perfectly according to the window size,

```js
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        console.log('addEventListener - resize2');
        let x = 1.3;

        x = window.innerHeight;
        
        if (window.innerWidth <= 1300){
            x=1.9;
        }
        else if (window.innerWidth <= 1100){
            x=1.9999999;
        }
        document.getElementById('bg_home').style.transform = `scale(1,${x})`;
    }, true);
}
```

but I feel like i'm rly stuck here trying to scale it according to window.innerHeight or window.InnerWidth seems rly hard, and honestly feel like my javascript solution would be too heavy. I also feel like i'm missing something very basic and i'm very sorry if it's the case.

Could someone please guide to a possible answer, else i'll probably have to screenshot my background and use it as an image

Comment: Any reasons against using `margin-top: - px` and responsive font-size or something along those lines?

Comment: No particular reason, I believe it's what I did try first like so: `.bg_home {
    color: var(--main-bg-color);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-stroke:  1px var(--text-stoke);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scale(1,1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1.3);
    font-size: 42vw;
    margin: 330px 0 0 0;
  }` . But it did not work

Comment: you want the background <p> to automatically scale to fill the majority of the background with the width as the priority or the height or both?

Comment: I'd like both actually